# How can get index for update datatable row

Tags: javascript, datatable

i wanna get datatable row index for `dataTableRow.row(rowIndex).data(rData).draw();` but i dont know how can i get this index. im use `dataTableRow.row(this).data(rData).draw();` like this but it always update index 0 in datatable.

```
obj = $("#" + key + "__" + customerCode);
                var row = $(obj).parent().parent()[0];
                var table = $(row).parent().parent()[0];
                var tableId = $(table).attr("id");
                var dataTable = $("#" + tableId).DataTable();
                var dataTableRow = dataTable.row($(row));

           var rData = [
                            customerCode,
                            name,
                            (identityNo.length > 0 ? identityNo : taxNo),
                            customerAdress.ADRESS_TEXT,
                            customerContact.TEXT,
                            lotInput,
                            deleteButton,
                            updateButton
                        ];
                        dataTableRow.row(this)
                            .data(rData)
                            .draw();
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to get the nth index you need to use jquery's `:eq` selector.

example:

`dataTable.row(':eq(' + index + ')').data().draw();`

if you wish to get the index of a row. use the `.index()`.

exmaple:

`dataTable.row({selected: true}).index();`

here's a list of all row selectors: https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector